# That machines can now play chess very well has been established

Tags: syntactic-analysis

dose that mean that the machine can now  play chess better than what was expected when it was being designed ?

This is The text

> On the other hand, other AI researchers have achieved spectacular results in getting particular aspects of human behaviour from machines. A good example would be chess playing. Certainly, when work started in this area in the 1950s it was seen as a good example of intelligent human behaviour. In a tournament in 1997 a computer called Deep Blue beat the World Chess Champion, Gary Kasparov. That machines can now play chess very well **has been established.**

Answer (score 2):

The sentence means that we know that machines can now play chess very well. You can think of it as meaning

> The fact that machines can now play chess very well has been established

or

> We have established the fact that machines can now play chess very
>   well.